# How do you use gradle's ``exclude`` to replace a dependency?

Tags: java, gradle, kotlin, dependencies, slf4j

So I want to disable logging for JUnit Tests.

Simplest way would be to switch the binding from `slf4j-simple` to `slf4j-nop`.

How do I do that, though?

I tried `exclude`:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"

    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$support_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'

    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-common:$anko_version"

    implementation "org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.6.1"
    testImplementation("org.slf4j:slf4j-nop:1.6.1"){
        exclude(group:'org.slf4j', module:'slf4j-simple')
    }
    implementation 'io.github.microutils:kotlin-logging:1.6.10'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

But that still results in

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/user1291/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/slf4j-nop/1.6.1/70249094d4e5653b6bdfea46f3a1a4165c1e1993/slf4j-nop-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/user1291/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple/1.6.1/58e59bfb3e247097b8122243b3bfe0049c8cfae8/slf4j-simple-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.helpers.NOPLoggerFactory]
```

Also tried `configurations`:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"

    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$support_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'

    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-common:$anko_version"

    implementation "org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.6.1"
    testImplementation "org.slf4j:slf4j-nop:1.6.1"
    implementation 'io.github.microutils:kotlin-logging:1.6.10'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

configurations{
    testImplementation.exclude(group:'org.slf4j',module:'slf4j-simple')
}
```

which made no difference.

Comment: the solution with `configurations` should work:  did you try to execute tests from an IDE or from command line?  I made simple to reproduce your problem, and from command line it's working fine ( slf4j-simple is excluded) but from IntelliJ IDEA: I get same error message with multiple slf4j bindings.. I guess this comes from how IDEA handle classpath for tests execution

Comment: @M.Ricciuti Andoid Studio, actually -- which is essentially IntelliJ. That's very interesting, though, thank you.

Comment: after more research:  Android Studio does not delegate test execution to Gradle test runner. In IntelliJ you have an option to chose between Platform or Gradle test runner, in project's Gradle configuration. This option is not present in Android Studio. Moreover, it seems that the Test classpath used by Intellij does not match exactly "testImplementation" configuration from Gradle, that's why your excluded library in gradle configuration is still present in classpath when running your test... If you run your test from "Gradle projects/tasks" panel, you should not have this error

Comment: Not optimal, but I guess it works, for now. Thank you. This is a somewhat strange design choice they took there ...

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
configurations.all { config ->
    config.resolutionStrategy.dependencySubstitution {
        if (config.name.toLowerCase().contains('test')) {
            substitute module('org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.6.1') with module('org.slf4j:slf4j-nop:1.6.1')
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope, afraid that doesn't make any difference.

Comment: It works for running from a terminal (not Android Studio)

Answer (score 0):

I would go a different route. SLF4J's simple logger will look for `simplelogger.properties` on your classpath. If you put that in `src/test/resources`, your test code should find it on the classpath, and you can use that to turn off SLF4J's output.

```
# src/test/resources/simplelogger.properties
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=off
```

You can see the full list of configuration properties, as well as a good description of simple logger [on its javadoc page](https://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/impl/SimpleLogger.html).

Comment: Hm ... I must be missing something. It just ignores the properties file.